# $A[X, Y ]/(X^2+Y^2−1)$ is integral domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, integral-domain, unique-factorization-domains

> Deduce that if $A$ is a unique factorization domain (UFD) of char-
> acteristic zero, then
> $A[X, Y ]/(X^2+Y^2−1)$ is an integral domain.

Let $B = A[X, Y]/(X^2 + Y^2 - 1)$, and suppose that $f(X, Y)$ and $g(X, Y)$ are elements of $B$ such that
$f(X, Y)g(X, Y) = 0$ in $B$. We need to show that either $f(X, Y) = 0$ or $g(X, Y) = 0$ in $B$.

Since $A$ is a $UFD$, it is an integral domain. Let $p(X)$ and $q(X)$ be the numerators of $f(X, Y)$ and $g(X, Y)$ respectively, so that
$f(X, Y) = p(X)/h(X)$ and $g(X, Y) = q(X)/k(X)$ for some polynomials $h(X)$ and $k(X)$ in $A[X]$ that are coprime with $X^2$ + $Y^2$ - $1$.

Multiplying the equation $f(X, Y)g(X, Y) = 0$ in $B$ by $h(X)k(X)$ gives $p(X)q(X) = 0$ in $A[X]$, which implies that either $p(X) = 0$ or $q(X) = 0$ in $A[X]$, since $A$ is an integral domain. Without loss of generality, assume that $p(X) = 0$ in $A[X]$.

Now let $r(Y)$ be the content of $h(X)$ in $A$, so that $h(X) = r(Y)s(X)$, where $s(X)$ is a primitive polynomial in $A[X]$. Since $h(X)$ is coprime with $X^2$ + $Y^2$- $1$, $s(X)$ is also coprime with $X^2$ + $Y^2$ - $1$. Therefore, we can write $s(X) = u(X) + v(X)Y$ for some polynomials $u(X)$ and $v(X)$ in $A[X]$. Substituting this expression into $h(X) = r(Y)s(X)$ and setting $X$ = $\sqrt(-1)$ gives $h(\sqrt(-1)) = 0$ in $A$, since $X^2$+ $Y^2$ - $1$ = $0$ in $B$ when $X$ = $\sqrt(-1)$ and $Y = 0$.

Since $A$ is a UFD of characteristic zero, it is also a Euclidean domain, and hence a principal ideal domain. Thus, we can write $r(Y) = a*d(Y)$, where $a$ is a unit in $A$ and $d(Y)$ is a monic irreducible polynomial in $A[Y]$. Since $h(\sqrt(-1)) = 0$ in $A$, we have $d(\sqrt(-1)) = 0$ in $A$, which implies that $d(Y)$ divides $Y^2$ + $1$ in $A[Y]$. However, since $A$ has characteristic zero, $Y^2$ + $1$ is irreducible in $A[Y]$, and hence $d(Y)$ is either $1$ or $Y^2$ + $1$.

If $d(Y) = 1$, then $h(X) = a$ for all $X$ in $A$, which implies that $f(X, Y) = p(X)/h(X)$ is a well-defined element of $A[X, Y]/(X^2 + Y^2 - 1)$, and hence $f(X, Y) = 0$ in $B$ implies that $p(X) = 0$ in $A[X]$. This in turn implies that $f(X, Y) = 0$ in $A[X, Y]/(X^2 + Y^2 - 1)$, since $p(X)$ and $h(X)$ are coprime in $A[X]$.

If $d(Y)$ = $Y^2$ + $1$, then $h(X)$ is irreducible in $A[X]$ and has degree at most two, since it divides $X^2$ + $Y^2$ - $1$, which is irreducible in $A[X, Y]$. Therefore, $h(X)$ is either $X$ - $\sqrt(-1)$, $X$ + $\sqrt(-1)$, or $X^2$ + $Y^2$ - $1$, up to associates in $A[X]$. In the first two cases, we can write $h(X)$ = $X$ - $\sqrt(-1)$ or $h(X)$ = $X$ + $\sqrt(-1)$, and hence $f(X, Y)$ = $p(X)$/($X$ - $\sqrt(-1)$) or $f(X, Y) = p(X)/(X + \sqrt(-1))$. In either case, we can write $f(X, Y) = a(X, Y) + b(X, Y)Y$, where $a(X, Y)$ and $b(X, Y)$ are polynomials in $A[X, Y]$.

Since $f(X, Y)$ is well-defined in $B$, we have $f(\sqrt(-1), 0) = a(\sqrt(-1), 0) = 0$ in $A$, which implies that $a(X, Y)$ is divisible by $X^2$ + $Y^2$ - $1$ in $A[X, Y]$. Therefore, we can write $a(X, Y) = (X^2 + Y^2 - 1)c(X, Y)$ for some polynomial $c(X, Y)$ in $A[X, Y]$. Substituting thisexpression into $f(X, Y) = a(X, Y) + b(X, Y)Y$ gives $f(X, Y) = (X^2 + Y^2 - 1)c(X, Y) + b(X, Y)Y$. Multiplying this equation by $h(X)$ gives $p(X) = (X^2 + Y^2 - 1)c(X, Y)s(X) + b(X, Y)Yr(Y)s(X)$, which implies that $p(X)$ is divisible by $X^2 + Y^2 - 1$ in $A[X]$, since $s(X)$ and $r(Y)$ are coprime with $X^2 + Y^2 - 1$. This contradicts the assumption that $p(X) = 0$ in $A[X]$, and hence we must have $d(Y) = 1$ in this case as well.

Therefore, we have shown that if $A$ is a UFD of characteristic zero, then $A[X, Y]/(X^2 + Y^2 - 1)$ is an integral domain.

Please cheak this...or give another solution...

Also 2nd prt is

> If the characteristics of $A$ is not zero .let the characteristics of $A$ is positive $p$. Then  Give a
> necessary and sufficient condition on $p$ such that $A[X,Y]/(X²+Y²-1)$ is integral domain.

> And now if $A$ is replaced by set of integers $ℤ$ then give examples of prime ideals in $ℤ[X,Y]/(X²+Y²-1)$ which are not maximal and give examples of maximal ideals in $ℤ[X,Y]/(X²+Y²-1)$.

Thank you

Comment: Not commenting on much, just the very end of your question, where it says "give examples of maximal ideals which are not prime" which is impossible, since maximal ideals are prime. (Remember that an ideal $I\subseteq R$ is prime if and only if $R/I$ is an integral domain, and $I$ is maximal if and only if $R/I$ is a field - but fields are integral domains, so maximal ideals are prime.)

Comment: @Frog yes you are right...I shall edit it..

Comment: Also I saw in your question that you wrote that $A$ being a UFD of characteristic zero implies it is a euclidean domain, but that's not true: every euclidean domain is a principal ideal domain, but when $K$ has characteristic zero, then $K[x_1,\dots, x_n]$ is a UFD of characteristic zero but not a PID (unless $n=1$).

Comment: What you need to show is that $x^2+y^2-1$ is an irreducible polynomial, then the ideal it generates in $A[x,y]$ will be prime. If you heard about Eisenstein's criterion, this is pretty easy.

Comment: How did you get rid of the $Y$ terms from $f$,$g$? It seems like you assume it’s a ratio of polynomials in X right off the bat. What is $\sqrt{-1}$? It’s not required such a term is an element of A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you only need the assumption that $\operatorname{char}(A)\neq 2$.

If $A$ is a UFD, so is $A[X]$ and thus also $A[X,Y]=(A[X])[Y]$.
An element $p\in A$ is prime iff $A/(p)$ is an integral domain. Moreover, in a UFD it holds that irreducible $\iff$ prime (in general only $\Leftarrow$ holds). Finally, for a UFD $R$ the Eisenstein-criterion holds: Given a monic polynomial $p=X^{n+1}+r_nX^n+...+r_0 \in R[X]$ and a prime ideal $\mathfrak p\subseteq R$ such that $r_i \in \mathfrak p$ for all $i$ and $r_0 \notin \mathfrak p^2$, then $p$ is irreducible.

Now consider the specific case $$R=A[X],\;\;p=Y^2+(X^2-1)\in R[Y],\;\;\mathfrak{p}=(X-1)\subseteq A[X].$$ We have $(X-1)^2 = (X^2 - 2X+1)$ and since $\operatorname{char}(A)\neq 2$ we find
$$X^2-1 = (X-1)(X+1) \in (X-1) \setminus (X-1)^2 = \frak{p\setminus p^2}.$$
By the Eisenstein criterion $p$ is irreducible / prime in $R[Y] = A[X,Y]$ making $A[X,Y]/(X^2+Y^2-1)$ an integral domain.

If $\operatorname{char}(A) = 2$ then
$$(X+Y+1)^2 = X^2+2XY+Y^2+2(X+Y)+1 = X^2+Y^2-1$$
(using that $2=0$ and $1=-1$), so $X^2+Y^2-1$ is **not** prime, in particular $A[X,Y]/(X^2+Y^2-1)$ is **not** an integral domain.